# Div Table with fixed right column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently took up a non-profit website as a project. I'm working with an existing website, so I'm having to work with a lot of the stuff already programmed, so all I have to do is create the design.

I made a diagram of basically what I can't figure out how to do:
[image]

I also made a JSFIDDLE of what is already there:http://jsfiddle.net/RmWu7/. I know I should of used a table for tabular data, but the programming is a bit weird, and I can't seem to figure out how to modify the php to work with a regular table, so I'm just going to keep the divs.

So two things:

1. I tried adding a `position:fixed` to .columns with the `.last` class, and an `overflow-x:auto` to the rest, but it completely messes up the layout.
2. How can I get the columns to be a fixed size instead of fluid, and have the last non-fixed column (before the columns with the .last class) to be bigger to fill up the table like in the diagram?

I'm trying to keep it mostly in CSS, but do I need to add jQuery as well?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Alright, I've finished my editing. I apologize if it annoyed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've totally change the codes as my previous version has problem on scrolling.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrap2">
            <div class='column'>
                <div class='row top'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
            </div>
            <div class='column'>
                <div class='row top'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
            </div>
            <div class='column'>
                <div class='row top'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
                <div class='row'>Test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column fixed-column'>
      <div class='row top'>Test</div>
      <div class='row'>Test</div>
      <div class='row'>Test</div>
      <div class='row'>Test</div>
      <div class='row'>Test</div>
      <div class='row'>Test</div>
      <div class='row'>Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.table{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    .wrap {
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
    .wrap2 {
        overflow: hidden;
        zoom: 1;
    }
    .column{
        float:left;
        background:red;
        width:200px;
        .row{
            padding:10px;
            &.top{
                background:green;
            }
        }
        &.fixed-column {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            background:blue;
        }
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var scrollingWidth = $('.table').innerWidth();
    var lastWidth = $('.table .wrap .column:last').outerWidth();
    var innerWidth = 0;
    $('.table .column').each(function() {
        innerWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
    });
    var gap = scrollingWidth - innerWidth + lastWidth;
    if(gap > lastWidth) {
        $('.table .wrap .column:last').css('width', gap);
        innerWidth += gap - lastWidth;
    }
    $('.table .wrap2').css('width', innerWidth);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is it possible to have it display as one table without the gap in between: http://jsfiddle.net/YPMz5/?

Comment: @the_ I'm editing, seems there's some other problem.