# Responsive Gap Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I found a question today that is similar to what I need for a project: [Div Table with fixed right column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213387/div-table-with-fixed-right-column).

Here's the jquery that is already there.:

```
$(function() {
  var scrollingWidth = $('.table').innerWidth();
  var lastWidth = $('.table .wrap .column:last').outerWidth();
  var innerWidth = 0;
  $('.table .column').each(function() {
     innerWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
  });
  var gap = scrollingWidth - innerWidth + lastWidth;
  if(gap > lastWidth) {
    $('.table .wrap .column:last').css('width', gap);
    innerWidth += gap - lastWidth;
  }
  $('.table .wrap2').css('width', innerWidth);
});
```

I also made a JSfiddle with all of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/U5Vn2/

So, getting to the issue:

If you never resize the window that the .table is in, then the code works perfect. But try to resize the window bigger than it was originally (without hitting **Run** again), then the code breaks. If you do hit **Run**, then it works at the larger size (unless of course you resize it even bigger).

Another issue is that the gap that the jQuery generates should get smaller if a scrollbar has to appear. (To demonstrate, resize the window and you have to scroll even though it is only gap space). Is this possible to fix?

I've been playing around with it this morning trying to get it to be responsive to larger sizes, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Listen to the resize event in jQuery and then make the adjustments you need? $(window).on("resize", function(){ //your code here })

Comment: Why don't you use a <table> tag?  It sounds as if you're trying to mimic its behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution to the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/znWAX/1/

```
$(function () {
   var gap, scrollingWidth, innerWidth = 0,
       lastWidth = $('.table .wrap .column:last').outerWidth();
   $('.table .column').each(function () {
       innerWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
   });

   function fixTableColumn() {
       scrollingWidth = $('.table').innerWidth();
       gap = scrollingWidth - innerWidth;
       if (gap > 0) {
           $('.table .wrap .column:last').css('width', gap + lastWidth);
       }
       $('.table .wrap2').css('width', innerWidth + Math.max(0, gap));
   }
   fixTableColumn();

   $(window).resize(function () {
       requestAnimationFrame(fixTableColumn);
   });
);
```

The basics of it is that you need to hook to window.onresize event and do appropriate calculations and actions - we actually need to calculate `innerWidth` and `lastWidth` only once and then on every resize - the `gap` and `scrollingWidth`.

The requestAnimationFrame function is used for fluid animation,
you can find more info about it here: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put your existing code into a function `setupTable()`, when the page loads for the first time execute `setupTable()`.

To make sure your table is updated each time the size of the browser window changes, you need to bind your `setupTable()` function to the "resize" event.

```
$(function() {
    // called when page is loaded
    setupTable();

    // triggered when the size of the browser window changes
    $(window).on("resize", setupTable);

    function setupTable(){
        var scrollingWidth = $('.table').innerWidth();
        var lastWidth = $('.table .wrap .column:last').outerWidth();
        var innerWidth = 0;
        $('.table .column').each(function() {
            innerWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
        });
        var gap = scrollingWidth - innerWidth + lastWidth;
        if(gap > lastWidth) {
            $('.table .wrap .column:last').css('width', gap);
            innerWidth += gap - lastWidth;
        }
        $('.table .wrap2').css('width', innerWidth);   
    }


});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This fixes the first problem, but it still creates a larger gap to scroll through when it doesn't need to: (see:http://jsfiddle.net/VvzMe/).